# Simple substitution cipher

Tags: java, encryption

Simple Substitution Cipher.

I'm trying to make a looping construct that would loop through a string,and at the same time write it to another string. I'm having trouble making it skip when it encounters a space. Can anybody help me out with this.

```
    String translate = "";//create empty string
int xxx = 0; //initialise counter
while(xxx < text.length()) {    //based on the original length of input text
if (text.charAt(xxx) != ' '){ //if no white space do this
translate = translate.concat(Character.toString((s2.charAt(copyS.indexOf(text.charAt(xxx))))));

} else { //if there is white space do this. (I'm unsure how to make it skip?)

}
xxx++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to skip the whitespace, then simply remove the `else` block. If you want to keep it, then add

```
translate = translate.concat(' ');
```

*Note* - My answer uses the same pattern that you used for the algorithm - it is terribly inefficient. If you want to *build* a String, then please have look at the `StringBuilder` class.